# Black flashing around drawn image

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics

I'm currently trying to draw an image to a JFrame (just a nonsense test image). In the code bite below, the image is drawn to the JFrame, but the area around the image that doesn't fill JFrame is black that rapidly flashes.

Here is the code below:

```
try {

        myImage = ImageIO.read(ImagesMain.class.getResource("/Textures/TestImage.png"));

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferStrategy strategy = null;

    while(strategy == null) {//I know this is terrible practice, just doing this way because its inside main

        strategy = myCanvas.getBufferStrategy();

        if(myCanvas.getBufferStrategy() == null) {
            myCanvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        }
    }



    myFrame.setVisible(true);

    //Rendering part


    while(true) {
        do {
            do {

                g = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawImage(myImage, 20, 20, null);
                g.dispose();

            }while(strategy.contentsRestored());

            strategy.show();

        }while(strategy.contentsLost());
    }
```

I've tested and retested my code several times to no avail. I should also add that this is all done in the main method (for testing purposes). Long story short, how do I display my image without the unnecessary black flashing around the image?

Comment: Since you're not clearing the `Graphics` context to an initial state, it's going to, repeatedly, paint what ever was originally painted to it and what ever you've now painted to it

Comment: MadProgrammer to the rescue again! Thanks man, cleared the rect & it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens, it is because one is not clearing the Frame to which they are drawing. In this instance,
`g.clearRect(x, y, height, width);` is needed to clear the drawing frame and display a clear image.

Answer courtesy of @MadProgrammer above, in comments.